# Send information through a website from one person to another instantaneously (like how a chatroom does)

Tags: javascript, api, rest, frontend, scaledrone

I have a chatroom. The API (Scaledrone) handles all of the server/back-end stuff, and is made of JavaScript. **If the API could transfer information from one user to another instantaneously with Javascript, then is there one where the information doesn't have to be restricted to sending messages to each other?** I want this for certain features, like kicking people out of chatrooms, or even making a feedback form with AJAX to backend servers on OTHER websites. I have looked at solutions, but these were only with back-end technologies, which makes sense. Could someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm well I'm not sure about the Scaledrone API, but if you want to send information between two users in just javascript and html you could try using WebRTC. Here's a link to something that might be useful: 
https://blog.logrocket.com/get-a-basic-chat-application-working-with-webrtc/

Comment: I'm sure it could work. I forgot to mention that my terminal is blocked and I have limited access to API keys. So I can't do it on my device right now. But thanks for an option as a last resort!:)